# Can QEMU support VT-x/AMD-v like VirtualBox in Windows

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu

The host is windows(xp and win7). The guest is a Android which build with x86 ABI by myselves.
I know if QEMU work with intel HAXM like google official emulator, it can support VT-x. But the big problem is HAXM NOT support AMD. And KVM support VT-x/AMD-v, but KVM can't use on Windows. So are there any other ways to let windows QEMU support VT-x/AMD-v like VirtualBox and VMware?

ps. In abstractive, for QEMU supporting CPU hardware virtualization, the function role of HAXM is just like KVM, is my understanding right?

Answer (score -3):

On linux, KVM can support VT-x/AMD-v.
But on windows, I don't know.